# Scoreboard in minigame seems to keep overwriteing its self how would i fix that in order to get a clear look at the scoreboard

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, overwrite

[https://gist.github.com/Ralph94/125934b8aaaf28764c30d0fbe2b18419]

```
import turtle  # Our module's

import random



score = 0

lives = 3





# Screen

ms = turtle.Screen()

ms.title("Falling Piece's mini_game by Rafa94")

ms.bgcolor("purple")

ms.setup(width=800, height=600)

ms.tracer(0.0)



# player

player = turtle.Turtle()

player.shape("turtle")

player.color("blue")

player.penup()

player.goto(0, -250)  # y is postive in the up direction y is negative in the down direction

player.speed(0)

player.direction = "stop"



# create a list of good players

goods = []  # Empty list



# Addgood players

for _ in range(20):  # we are making a set of 20 players

    good = turtle.Turtle()  # we want the other player basically across from each other thats we copyed the code one on -y and one on +y (first player in the bottom, second player on top of Screen)

    good.speed(0)

    good.shape("circle")

    good.color("red")

    good.penup()

    good.goto(-100, 250)  # y is postive in the up direction y is negative in the down direction

    good.speed = random.randint(1, 4)

    goods.append(good)



# create a list of bad players

bads = []  # Empty list



# Addbad players

for _ in range(20):  # we are making a set of 20 players

    bad = turtle.Turtle()  # we want the other player basically across from each other thats we copyed the code one on -y and one on +y (first player in the bottom, second player on top of Screen)

    bad.speed(0)

    bad.shape("circle")

    bad.color("yellow")

    bad.penup()

    bad.goto(100, 250)  # y is postive in the up direction y is negative in the down direction

    bad.speed = random.randint(1, 4)

    bads.append(bad)



    # make the pen

    pen = turtle.Turtle()

    pen.hideturtle()

    pen.speed(0)

    pen.shape("turtle")

    pen.color("blue")

    pen.penup()

    pen.goto(0, 260)  # y is postive in the up direction y is negative in the down direction

    font = ("Courier", 24, "normal")

    pen.write("Score: {} Lives: {}".format(score, lives), align="center", font=font)











# Functions

def go_left():

    player.direction = "left"





def go_right():

    player.direction = "right"





# keyboard Binding

ms.listen()  # it is bascally saying listen for keyboard input < ^ >

ms.onkeypress(go_left, "Left")

ms.onkeypress(go_right, "Right")



# Main game loop # while something is true it will repeat

while True:

    # update screen

    ms.update()



    # Move player

    if player.direction == "left":

        x = player.xcor()

        x -= + 3

        player.setx(x)



    if player.direction == "right":

        x = player.xcor()

        x += + 3

        player.setx(x)



    # Move Good Player

    for good in goods:

        y = good.ycor()

        y -= good.speed  # We want the ball to be falling at a smooth speed

        good.sety(y)

        # Check it off the Screen

        if y < -300:

            x = random.randint(-380, 380)

            y = random.randint(300, 400)

            good.goto(x, y)



        # check for collision with player

        if good.distance(player) < 20:

            x = random.randint(-380, 380)

            y = random.randint(300, 400)

            good.goto(x, y)

            score += 10

            pen.clear()

            pen.write("Score: {} Lives: {}".format(score, lives), align="center", font=font)







    # Move bad Player

    for bad in bads:

        y = bad.ycor()

        y -= bad.speed  # We want the ball to be falling at a slow speed

        bad.sety(y)

        # Check it off the Screen

        if y < -300:

            x = random.randint(-380, 380)

            y = random.randint(300, 400)

            bad.goto(x, y)



        # check for collision with player

        if bad.distance(player) < 20:

            x = random.randint(-380, 380)

            y = random.randint(300, 400)

            bad.goto(x, y)

            score -= 10

            lives -= 1

            pen.clear()

            pen.write("Score: {} Lives: {}".format(score, lives), align="center", font=font)



ms.mainloop()
```

Comment: Post the code in your question, not as a link to github.

Comment: describe problem in question's body, not in its title. Create minimal working code with problem. Remove some empty lines in code.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong indentions and you make `pen` in `for`-loop so you create 20 pens and every pen write string. Later `pen.clear()` can remove only last string but there are still other strings create by other 19 pens.

Create `pen` after `for`-loop and you will have only one pen and it will works correctly.